# SQLite, DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I'm trying to populate my my RecyclerViewAdapter by using tables name from the sqlite database, every thing is working absolutely fine without any error but lagging in opening an activity containing this adapter.
with this Logcat:

```
E/Path 1: /data/data/com.shahzadakram67.soloacademy/databases/
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
```

> E/Path
>   1: /data/data/com.shahzadakram67.soloacademy/databases/

This first line repeats as many time as the number of tables in my database.

**Adapter Code:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    //code to count the rows in each table
    LocalDatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new LocalDatabaseHelper(mContext);
    Cursor c = myDbHelper.getAllData(mData.get(position).getTableName());
    holder.topicName.setText(mData.get(position).getTableName());
    holder.topicDetails.setText(c.getCount());

}
```

My personal Assessment is that I added code to count the number of rows in all tables makes it lagging because it was working fine before, I have huge number of tables,  its not possible to count rows for all table one by one and change them on different occasions, How to make it fast like before?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue using SharedPrefrences.

```
    SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("prefName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    Integer recordCount = pref.getInt(mData.get(position).getTableName(), 0);

    if (quizCount < 1){
        for(int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++){
            Cursor c = myDbHelper.getAllData(mData.get(i).getTableName());
            editor.putInt(mData.get(i).getTableName(), c.getCount());
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
```